# Java cast parent to child?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
for (DrawableEntity entity : drawableEntityList) {
    if (entity instanceof Beam) {
        (Beam) entity.age += timeElapsed;
    }
    else if (entity instanceof Block) {

    }
}
```

Basically `drawableEntityList` is a `Vector` of `DrawableEntitys`, and I want to iterate through everything in the `Vector`. Then depending on if they are subclass `Beam` or subclass `Block` I want to do something different.

The problem is that I'm trying to change a variable that only the subclasses have, I figured I could cast with (Beam) but it doesn't work.

Is it not possible to cast a parent class to a child class?

Comment: Just guessing: `((Beam) entity).age += timeElapsed;`

Comment: The member access operator (`.`) has a higher precedence than the cast operator (`(Type)`), so writing `(Beam) entity.age += timeElapsed;` is equivalent to `((Beam) entity.age) += timeElapsed;`. This gives two errors: (1) `entity.age` cannot be cast to `Beam`, and (2), an expression of type `Beam` is not applicable as the left operand of the `+=` operator. I hope this helps understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your casting syntax is not right.

Try this

```
if (entity instanceof Beam) {
    ((Beam) entity).age += timeElapsed;
}
else if (entity instanceof Block) {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Notes: Beware of `instanceof` operator

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31